# How to fix 401 unauthorized error, when using signInWithPassword, in a next js project with Supabase?

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, supabase

**Description:**
I'm currently working on a Next JS v.14 project with supabase for authentication and database storage. I've never worked with supabase in the past so all of this is new to me. I followed a [tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dhXjHGklaZc) for the email and password authentication. While, it works sometimes, in most cases it doesn't allow me to sign in on the website although on the supabase dashboard it says I've signed in. By looking in the console I found an error. From what I understood from the video the process im following has to do with creating a session and then using cookies to store that session and then whenever I need to connect to supabase it uses that session. Would the issue stem from the session, cookies or is this a supabase issue? If i'm getting anything wrong please feel free to correct me. If you have any ideas on the issue or the error or just need more information please let me know. Thank you!

**Error:**

> GET https://dswgtkzjdoyjmrhbzveo.supabase.co/auth/v1/user 401 (Unauthorized)

**Code for `login/route.js`:**

```
'use client'

import { createClientComponentClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs"
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

export default function Login(){
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const router = useRouter()
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  
  const supabase = createClientComponentClient();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUser(){
      const {data: {user}} = await supabase.auth.getUser();
      setUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    }

    getUser();
  }, [])

  const handleSignUp = async () => {
    const res =await supabase.auth.signUp({
      email, 
      password,
      options: {
        emailRedirectTo: `$(location.origin)/auth/callback`
      }
    });
    setUser(res.data.user);
    router.refresh();
    setEmail('');
    setPassword('');
  }

  const handleSignIn = async () => {
    const res = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
      email,
      password
    });
    setUser(res.data.user);
    router.refresh();
    setEmail('');
    setPassword('');
  }

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    await supabase.auth.signOut();
    router.refresh();
    setUser(null)
  }

  console.log(loading, user);
  if (loading){
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>
  }

  if (user){
    return (
      <div className="h-screen flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-gray-100">
        <div className="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 p-8 rounded-lg shadow-md w-96 text-center">
          <h1 className="mb-4 text-xl font-bold text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300">You're already logged in</h1>
            <button onClick={handleLogout} className="w-full p-3 rounded-md bg-red-500 text-white hover:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none">Logout</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <main className="hero min-h-screen bg-primary">
      <div className="hero-content flex-col lg:flex-row-reverse">
        <div className="text-center lg:text-left">
          <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold">Login now!</h1>
          <p className="py-6">Provident cupiditate voluptatem et in. Quaerat fugiat ut assumenda excepturi exercitationem quasi. In deleniti eaque aut repudiandae et a id nisi.</p>
        </div>
        <div className="card shrink-0 w-full max-w-sm shadow-2xl bg-base-100">
          <form className="card-body">
            <div className="form-control">
              <label className="label">
                <span className="label-text">Email</span>
              </label>
              <input type="email" name="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} className="mb-4 w-full input input-bordered" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-control">
              <label className="label">
                <span className="label-text">Password</span>
              </label>
              <input type="password" name="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} className="mb-4 w-full input input-bordered" />
              <label className="label">
                <a href="#" className="label-text-alt link link-hover">Forgot password?</a>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-control mt-6">
              <button className="w-full mb-2 btn btn-primary" onClick={handleSignUp}>Sign Up</button>
              <button className="w-full btn btn-default" onClick={handleSignIn}>Sign In</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

**Code for `auth/callback/route.js`**

```
import {createRouteHandlerClient} from 'supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import {cookies} from 'next/headers'
import {NextResponse} from 'next/server'

export async function GET(request){
  const requestUrl = new URL(request.url);
  const code = requestUrl.searchParams.get('code');
  if (code){
    const cookieStore = cookies();
    const supabase = createRouteHandlerClient({cookies: () => cookieStore});
    await supabase.auth.exchangeCodeForSession(code);
  }
  return NextResponse.redirect(requestUrl.origin);
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to use the official template from here: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/quickstarts/nextjs

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at it but the issue is it doesn't give much information about how to use email and password authentication.